# About binarySearch() of Kotlin List

Tags: kotlin

I ran the examples in the official Kotlin documentation in the local Android Studio, and found that the results are different from what I expected, but I don’t know what is causing this?

```
    data class Produce(
    val name: String,
    val price: Double
)
```

This is the data class I defined

```
 val list2 = listOf(
        Produce("AppCode", 52.0),
        Produce("IDEA", 182.0),
        Produce("VSCode", 2.75),
        Produce("Eclipse", 1.75)
    )
```

this is my source list

```
 println(list2.sortedWith(compareBy<Produce> {
        it.price
    }.thenBy {
        it.name
    }))
```

The output on the console is:

```
[Produce(name=Eclipse, price=1.75), Produce(name=VSCode, price=2.75), Produce(name=AppCode, price=52.0), Produce(name=IDEA, price=182.0)]
```

I call `binarySearch()` like this

```
println("result: ${
        list2.binarySearch(
            Produce("AppCode", 52.0), compareBy<Produce> {
                it.price
            }.thenBy {
                it.name
            }
        )
    }")
```

I think the result should be 2, but it is 0

```
result: 0
```

I don't know why it turned out like this. Plase help me . thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sortedWith()` does not modify the list, it returns a new, sorted collection. When calling `list2.binarySearch()` you still search through original, unsorted list.

You need to either do something like:

```
list2.sortedWith().binarySearch()
```

Or create your list with `mutableListOf()` and then use `sort()` which sorts in-place.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. In kotlin, binarySearch() can use comparator as its parameter. In the above print, I just observe the sorted list.

Comment: Yes, you can provide a comparator to `binarySaerch()`, but that doesn't mean it will sort with this comparator. You provide it to tell `binarySearch()` what is the sorting algorithm that was **already** applied to the collection. Docs say: "The list is expected to be sorted into ascending order according to the specified comparator, otherwise the result is undefined.". It is expected, meaning that `binarySearch()` requires that collection is already sorted with provided comparator. You provided unsorted collection, so you got this undefined behavior mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I think I fully understand what this function does.

Answer (score 2):

Broot is right. You need to pass the *sorted* list to the `binarySearch()` function. To clarify in code:

```
val comparator = compareBy<Produce> { it.price }.thenBy { it.name }
val sorted = list2.sortedWith(comparator)
println(sorted.joinToString("\n"))
val foundIndex = sorted.binarySearch(Produce("AppCode", 52.0), comparator)
println("Found at: $foundIndex")
```

Result:

```
Produce(name=Eclipse, price=1.75)
Produce(name=VSCode, price=2.75)
Produce(name=AppCode, price=52.0)
Produce(name=IDEA, price=182.0)
Found at: 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, through your code, I can clearly understand the role of this function.